# How to store fig in .mat file?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to store the matlab figure inside a mat file, where the variable are stored.

I got into a scenario where i generated some plot from the variable stored in the mat file. Currently im storing the figure as a separate file, this means, i have a 1 file for variables and another file for figure. But i would like to bundle them together in a single file.

Comment: A glance at the documentation for MAT files indicates that the answer to your first question 'Is it possible ...' is no.

Answer (score 4):

How about selecting both files in the windows explorer and zip them? ;-)

Seriously, while I do not know of a way to do exactly what you want (what is it, exactly, anyway? Do you expect the figure to pop up once you've typed `load variables.mat` and pressed enter?) I see this way around it:

You could store the command(s) needed to generate the figure in an anonymous function or as a string and save it along with all other variables. Then, after loading the `.mat` file, you call that function or `eval` on the string and the figure will be regenerated.

```
x=sort(rand(1,100)); y=sort(randn(1,100)); %# sample data
makefig = @() plot(x,y,'g.'); %# anonymous figure-generating function
save myDataAndFigure

clear all
load myDataAndFigure
makefig()
```

...or, with a string (e.g. when including formatting and axis-labelling commands)

```
x=sort(rand(1,100)); y=sort(randn(1,100)); %# sample data
figcmd = 'plot(x,y,''g.''); xlabel(''sort(U(0,1)''); ylabel(''sort(N(1,0)'');'
save myDataAndFigure

clear all
load myDataAndFigure
eval(figcmd)
```

The latter should save memory when the involved data are large, since the anonymous function object contains all the data it needs, i.e. its own "copy" of `x` and `y` in the example.

Comment: `zip` is even a Matlab function

Answer (score 3):

There's an article [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/) on fig file format and how it's actually a mat file in a disguise.

So you can take the fig and store its data in a structs and save them as a mat file, then load the mat file and make fig out of the structs you saved.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing data and functions in instances of a class and unsing the functions later to plot the data?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is surprisingly easy to do.

Suppose you have just created the figure in question.  Converting the figure handle into a struct yields the corresponding hierarchical elements (including the data, labels, everything) required to display the figure.

If desired, this struct may then be saved to a mat file just as though it was data. (It is, in fact.)  To view the contents of the struct as a figure again simply reconvert it to a handle with struct2handle.

```
% The line below converts the current figure handle into a struct.
this_fig = handle2struct(gcf) 

% The line below converts the struct "this_fig"  back to a figure handle and displays it.    
h = struct2handle(this_fig,0);
```